# Error comparing dask date month with an integer

Tags: python, pandas, dask

The dask map_partitions function in the code below has a dask date field where its month is compared to an integer. This comparison fails with the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What is this error and how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import datetime

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'balance': [150, 140, 130, 280, 260],
    'date2' : [datetime.datetime(2021,3,1), datetime.datetime(2021,4,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,5,1), datetime.datetime(2021,1,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,2,1)]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1) 

def func2(obj):
    m = obj.date2.dt.month
    if m > 10:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

ddf2 = ddf.map_partitions(func2, meta=int)
ddf2.compute()   # <-- fails here
```

Comment: Looks like `obj` is a data-frame-like object. Do maybe you want to try something like: `return (obj.date2.dt.month <= 10) + 1` (it's relying on the boolean series of  trues and falses, being upcast to 1s and 0s respectively. Also, note that I've inverted the condition). Anyway, the long and short, is you should be returning an array-like of ints which is the same length as your data frame.

Comment: note that the problem isn't that you're *returning* an int, it's that you're using an if statement that resolves to a series, which can't be coerced into a bool. You cannot do `if pd.Series(range(20)) > 10: print('success!')` - python can't interpret the series as a True or False value (or rather, pandas does't let you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.map_partition`, each dask dataframe partition (which is a pandas dataframe) is passed to the function `func2`. As a result, `obj.date2.dt.month` refers to a Series, not a single value, so by running the comparison with the integer, it's not clear to Python whether how to determine the validity of the comparison.

As one option, below is a snippet that creates a new column, conditional on `dt.month` result:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import datetime

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'balance': [150, 140, 130, 280, 260],
    'date2' : [datetime.datetime(2021,3,1), datetime.datetime(2021,4,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,5,1), datetime.datetime(2021,1,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,2,1)]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1) 

def func2(obj):
    m = obj.date2.dt.month
    obj.loc[m>10, 'new_int']=1
    obj.loc[m<=10, 'new_int']=2
    return obj

ddf2 = ddf.map_partitions(func2)
ddf2.compute()
```